# scrapy removing duplicates at spider level

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there a way in scrapy to get the current request queue or build it dynamically using scrapy?

The use case that I have is that I have product listing page and there are multiple filters present on this page. These filters result in different urls (because of different query strings) but actually the products listed are same. So what I want to do is first get all urls for all products using various filters and then remove the duplicates at the spider level itself and add metadata to the request about the filters which result in same product.

This way I can identify the duplicates without actually parsing the product page first and also associate a metadata with the item.

Pseudocode for what I want to achieve:

```
def parse(self, response):
    filter_pages = for all filter links present on the page download/request the filtered page

    all_urls = []
    for filter in filter_pages:
        url = scrape url for all product/item links
        all_urls.append(url)

    for url in all_urls:
        filter_tags = identify duplicates in all_urls (based on the product id present in query string) and returns csv filters that resulted in duplicates.
        request = Request(url, callback = self.parseItem)
        request.meta['tag'] =  filter_tags
        yield request
```

Comment: Have you looked at [one of the snippets from scrapy](http://snippets.scrapy.org/snippets/1/)? They create a middleware for that purpose. You meed need to update it a little bit if it fails to work with the latest version of Scrapy, but I think that should be a minor task.

Comment: Yeah I had a look at the snippet but it seems that the latest version of scrapy already ignores the visited links via I think RFPDupeFilter  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class. The purpose is not just to remove duplicates but to identify different categories that a product could be reached from different urls.